# How to signal a buffer full state between posix threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

I have two threads, the main thread 'A' is responsible for message handling between a number of processes. When thread A gets a buffer full message, it should inform thread B and pass a pointer to the buffer which thread B will then process.

When thread B has finished it should inform thread A that it has finished.

How do I go about implementing this using posix threads using C on linux. I have looked at conditional variables, is this the way to go? . I'm not experienced in multi threaded programming and would like some advice on the best avenue to take.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, conditional variables and mutexes are two things you have to use when implement your solution.

You can take a look at the section "[A few ways to use threads](http://books.google.com/books?id=_xvnuFzo7q0C&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=Programming+with+POSIX+A+few+ways+to+use+threads&source=bl&ots=Km4P0XZ7Vh&sig=zSURH8MyU5mvoqXRg4N65_hZ5S0&hl=en&ei=z27NS_azOsz5OZqD_fQP&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)" on explanation how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you relax the conditions that the buffer must be full before B starts processing it and that the buffer must be empty before A starts filling it again, then this is the classic [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producers-consumers_problem).

If you cannot relax those conditions, then I do not see the benefit of separating the functionality between two threads.  Since thread A cannot add to the buffer while thread B is processing, and thread B cannot do any processing while thread A is adding to the buffer, then all the work can be done in a single thread.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However I can only start Thread 'B' when I get a buffer full message from another process running on the system. Thread 'A' is used to manage the message queues. Thread A needs to be able to determine when thread 'B' has finished processing so that it can send a message to another process running on the system. What would be the best way of doing this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using a posix semaphore to represent 'number of filled buffers'. The pointers could be passed over a shared ring buffer. Depending on how you want to handle overflows, you may need to protect it with a mutex.